# Blazor - <select> not firing edtform context model changes

Tags: c#, blazor

I have an order page in my blazor app that accepts details of an order, with a table where order lines are added.  I have a function called "CalculateTotals()" which needs to be called every time a field is changed, like quantity or unit price, to update the totals in the UI, before the user submits the order form.

It seems that all of the functionality works fine for any controls other than `<select>`. In each order line there is also a collection of "taxes".  This is presented by looping through the tax lines, per order line and showing a dropdown where the user selects a tax code.  When the selection is made, it seems that @onchange is triggered, as I can see the value change in the json output of the model, but the CalculateTotals function is never called, so the onfieldchanged event in my code isn't being triggered.  It seems that it is doing this for any `<select>` that I use, regardless of where it is in the editform.  I use  instead of `<InputSelect>` as my dropdown values are Guids.  Anyone have an idea why the `onFieldChange` event wouldn't be triggered as a model field change?  Below is a snippit of my code.

```
<EditForm EditContext="@formContext">    
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table mt-4" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Quantity</th>
                                            <th>Unit Cost</th>
                                            <th>Taxes</th>
                                            <th class="text-right">Total</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                        @if (order.OrderLines != null)
                                        {
                                            foreach (var line in order.OrderLines.OrderBy(x => x.LineNumber))
                                            {
                                            <tr >

                                                <div id="dragdiv" class="dragula-handle" draggable="true" @ondrop="@(()=> Drop(line))" @ondrag="@(()=> StartDrag(line))" @key="line.Id"></div>

                                                    <td>
                                                        <InputText id="item-desc" @bind-Value="line.Description" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@FormDisabled" placeholder="Description" />
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td>
                                                        <InputNumber id="item-qty" @bind-Value="line.Quantity" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@FormDisabled" placeholder="Qty" />
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td>
                                                        <InputNumber id="item-unit-cost" @bind-Value="@line.AmountPerUnit" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@FormDisabled" placeholder="Unit Cost" />
                                                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => line.AmountPerUnit)" />
                                                    </td>

                                                    <td>
                                                        @if (line.Taxes != null)
                                                        {
                                                            foreach (var tax in line.Taxes)
                                                            { 
                                                            <select id="tax-@tax.TaxCodeId" @bind="tax.TaxCodeId" class="form-control">
                                                                @if (taxCodes != null)
                                                                {
                                                                    foreach (var taxcode in taxCodes)
                                                                    {
                                                                        <option value="@taxcode.Id">@taxcode.Name</option>
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            </select>
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div> <!-- end table-responsive-->
                        </div> <!-- end col -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end row -->
                </div> <!-- end card-body-->
            </div> <!-- end card -->
        </div> <!-- end col-->
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Load();

        formContext = new EditContext(order);
        formContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender,FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName);

        if (formContext.Validate())
        {
            // You can validate the EditContext here, and do necessary 
            CalculateTotals();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `Input*` receive the [`EditForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)'s [`EditContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in a cascading parameter. When the value change, they call [`EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b73e221c64397487cc1846bf14b72d128e97b3ca/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs#L71) that trigger the field validation.

If you don't use `InputSelect` there isn't field validation. But you can make your own 
`select` component.

Comment: ok, so the easiest here would be to try and use InputSelect rather, however I see there's a bug still for it not supporting Guid values. Is the only way of getting around that trying to convert to string?

Comment: @Tjopsta If I had to do it, I'll probably create my InputSelect derived from MS InputSelect converting the GUID to string.

Comment: Perfect... wasn't such a big deal after all... changed my Webapi to present Ids as string and we're good to go.  Thanks for your guidance afm.